# How to build debug symbols from source?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel

I want to use Kdump and Crash to debug my kernel. However, my kernel was built from source. I can't get debug symbols through `apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r)-dbg`. How could I build `-dbg` from source?

My OS is Ubuntu 20.04 and kernel is v5.15.0.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily compile the kernel with debug symbols by enabling `CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO`. If you are using `make menuconfig` it's going to be under *"Kernel hacking" -> "Compile-time checks and compiler options" -> "Compiler a kernel with debug info"*.

If you want to have the debug symbols split in a different `.dwo` file you can also enable `CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_SPLIT` (same location in the menu). This should be more or less the same thing that the `linux-image-$(uname -r)-dbg` package contains.